# CSS Анимация тени влево и вправо от центра блока

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать анимированую тень для текста (слова), как на картинке.

Вот что я сделал, но это ужасно и вообще не очень похоже.

```
.div::before{
box-sizing: inherit;
content: '';
position: absolute;
left:15px;
top: 18px;
animation: shadow_pas;              
animation-timing-function: ease-out;        
animation-direction: normal;            
animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
animation-duration: 1.15s;              
}

@keyframes shadow_pas {
to {box-shadow:150px 0 36px 0 #d1b887,
                130px 0 36px 1px #d1b887,
                110px 0 36px 2px #d1b887,
                90px 0 36px 3px #d1b887,
                70px 0 36px 4px #d1b887,
                50px 0 36px 5px #d1b887,
                30px 0 36px 5px #d1b887,
                10px 0 36px 5px #d1b887,
                0 0 36px 5px #d1b887,
                -10px 0 36px 5px #d1b887,
                -30px 0 36px 5px #d1b887,
                -50px 0 36px 4px #d1b887,
                -70px 0 36px 3px #d1b887,
                -90px 0 36px 2px #d1b887,
                -110px 0 36px 1px #d1b887,
                -130px 0 36px 0 #d1b887;
}
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Может у кого уже есть готовое решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сложно угадать анимацию по статичной картинке, но я вижу это примерно так:

```css
body {
  background: rgba(55, 30, 10, 1);
}

.pass {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0 3.5em;
  font: bold 24px/30px 'Arial';
  color: rgba(220, 190, 140, 1);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(209, 184, 135, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%) center center no-repeat;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out infinite back_shine;
}

@keyframes back_shine {
  0%, 100% { background-size: 90%; }
  50% { background-size: 30%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="pass">Пас</div>
```

Comment: извините, что не сразу отреагировал на Ваш ответ. Спасибо большое, что подсказали, что можно вообще обойтись без теней, заменив их фоновым градиентом.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра рад, что смог помочь. Стараюсь всё делать нативом (т.е. без сторонних библиотек и тп.), а также не спешу с применением новых технологий, ибо - WinXP + Chrome49 живее всех живых (про IE умолчу ))